# Google Maps API didDrag, didBeginDragging, didEndDragging functions do not work

Tags: swift

I have set up a single marker on the map view and I am using **GMSMapViewDelegate** and implementing the following functions:

> - mapView:didBeginDraggingMarker:
> - mapView:didEndDraggingMarker:
> - mapView:didDragMarker:

I have tried reinstalling the pods but nothing I do seems to work. I have been stuck on this problem for the past 5 days and still no luck.

```
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    var mapView = GMSMapView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This function fetches data from the server and places marker
        makeRequest()

        self.marker.isDraggable = true

        // Create a map with the location based on user's country
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: defaults.value(forKey: map.lat) as! CLLocationDegrees,
                                              longitude: defaults.value(forKey: map.lon) as! CLLocationDegrees,
                                              zoom: defaults.value(forKey: map.zoom) as! Float)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("DidBeginDragging")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didEndDragging")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didDrag")
    }
}
```

I can drag the marker but I cannot seem to run the three delegate functions.

Comment: Please set the mapview delegate to self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you missed setting the delegate:

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

at the top change the `var mapView = GMSMapView()` to `var mapView: GMSMapView?`

The way you have it, you're creating a mapView and then creating a new one in viewDidLoad

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events)

Comment: Thanks. I added it to the viewDidLoad function but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3348166 How are you creating the views?  Programmatically or via storyyboard? at the top change the `var mapView = GMSMapView()` to `var mapView: GMSMapView?` or create an iboutlet for the mapview

Comment: It seems like i have forgotten to add `self.view = self`.